# How to understand the limit in the generalized real system?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

As stated on the title:

How to understand a sequence limit in the generalized real system $[-\infty,\infty]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as in the typical case of $\mathbb{R}$.  The only difference is that now, having a limit of $\infty$ or $-\infty$ counts as *converging*, rather than diverging.

Comment: That's every sequence of real numbers has a limit,does it ?

Comment: But note that the generalized real system is not a field.

Comment: @mathon: no, of course not. e.g. $0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$.

Comment: Oh,yes,I have made a stupid mistake.